# textfield for ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

i am very new to `iOS` and xcode. i want to create a textfield without using nib files or storyboard. i searched for the answers but everywhere its kind of confusing or they have used nib files. i have created buttons and its working fine but for textfields m facing problems. here is my `viewcontroller.m` please help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView {


self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UITextField *textfield;


button.frame = CGRectMake(10 ,350 , 300, 40);
button1.frame = CGRectMake(10 ,50 , 300, 40);
textfield.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 30);


[button setTitle:@"Change screen to green!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitle:@"click screen to red!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:textfield];
}
-(void)buttonPressed {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

}
-(void)buttonPressed1 {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added the alloc init like the answers have suggested, your text field is in fact on the screen, but since it has no border or no text, you can't see it. Try adding this line, and then you will see it:

```
textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just declared the `UITextField` instead of allocating. You must allocate it first then set `frame` & add it on the `view` like -

```
UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
txt.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 30);
txt.delegate = self;
[self.view adsubview:txt];
```

It solves your problem.

Comment: This seems to fix the issue @Shanu Singh

Comment: thanks @Girish. but when i am using delegate its throwing me a warning and i am not able to see textfield on screen.

Comment: Set the UITextFieldDelegate in the .h file like @interface SearchWineViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> & implements delegate methods in .m file. Also set proper frame to show the textfield.

Comment: i have set delegate in .h file and implemented in .m file but still i cant see the text field on my screen..

Comment: try to set the proper the frame.

Comment: @Girish thanks for help. just added this line textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; and its working now. it was there but i should have given border style.

Answer (score 1):

First use

```
UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
UITextField *textfield;
```

Then set backgroud color of textfield since the backgroud color will be clearColor by default.

```
textfield.backgroundColor   =   [UIColor whiteColor];
```

or use

```
textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

to get white colored bordered text field.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

Insetd of

```
UITextField *textfield;
```

`UITextField *textfield;` Just crete object reference Not object.

Comment: thanks @CRDave i did that but still i cant see the textfield on my screen.

Comment: UITextField *textfield =[[UITextField alloc] init];
    
    
    
    textfield.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 30);
    textfield.delegate = self;
    
    
    
    [self.view addSubview:textfield];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end

Comment: i just want to create a textfield. this is what is in my .m file but still i cant see that textfield on my screen.

Comment: hmm problem seem something else. edit your question with .h and .m file code.

Comment: thanks for help. just added this line textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect; and its working now. it was there but i should have given border style.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *textfield =[[UITextField alloc] init];
 textfield.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 30); 
textfield.delegate = self; [self.view addSubview:textfield];
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:textfield];
```

may solve the problem